# How to use list comprehension to select lower value between 2 lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
a = list of number with length k
b = list of number with length k
```

How to get a list c with the lower value of a and b, position by position?

```
Example:
a = [0.6, 0.8, 0.4]
b = [0.4, 1.0, 0.5]

c = [0.4, 0.8, 0.4]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) like this:

```
c = [min(*item) for item in zip(a, b)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> a = [0.6, 0.8, 0.4]
>>> b = [0.4, 1.0, 0.5]
>>>
>>> c = [min(*item) for item in zip(a, b)]
>>> c
[0.4, 0.8, 0.4]
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use the `for` with `zip()` like that. Really liked that!

Comment: @Lucas Python is powerful ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just pass `map` two list arguments:

```
c = map(min, a, b)
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this won't return a list on python3.x -- It'll return an iterable object which yields the expected items.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of `min` and `zip`:

```
c = [min(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]
```

If you're going to do computations like this a lot, it might be worth using `numpy`:

```
c = numpy.minimum(a, b)
```

e.g.:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([0.6, 0.8, 0.4])
>>> b = numpy.array([0.4, 1.0, 0.5])
>>> numpy.minimum(a, b)
array([ 0.4,  0.8,  0.4])
```

Comment: I didn't know `np.minimum` did the comparison pairwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy's [minimum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) function which does element-wise minimum of array elements.

```
numpy.minimum(a, b)
```